# C++ Array swapping and find smallest element

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to find first smallest array but my code does not display any output. There are no errors or warnings. Actually, I am trying to check an algorithm that I got as an assignment from my university.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int arr[7]= {8,4,6,9,2,3,1};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int smallest = 0;
    for(int j = 1; j = (n-1); j = (j + 1) )
    {
        smallest= j ;
        for(int i = (j+1); i = n ; i = (i + 1))
        {
            if (arr[i]<arr[smallest])
            {
                smallest = i;
                int swaper = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[smallest];
                arr[smallest] = swaper;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int a = 1; a = n; a = (a + 1))
    {
        cout<<arr[a];
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: In all of the exit checks for your for loops you have `=` not `==`. This is assigning, not checking for equality. This means your loops will never exit.

Comment: Please, when asking people to spend time trying to solve your problem, do them the courtesy of indenting your code properly, and using a consistent spacing.  (I see Yksisarvinen has just done it for you this time - but really, you shouldn't rely on other people like that.)

Answer (score 4):

There are three errors with this code:

> ```
>     for(int a = 1; a = n; a = (a + 1))
>     {
>         cout<<arr[a];
>     }
> ```

Firstly, arrays start from zero, not one.  So the first part of the for statement should be `int a = 0;`.

Secondly, you are not *comparing* `a` and `n`, you are *assigning* `n` to `a`, (and the value is non-zero, so you always keep going).  The equality test is `==`, but you don't want that anyway!

Thirdly, the loop condition is for when to keep going, not when to stop.  So you need either `<` or `!=` (either will work, people have long arguments about which is preferable).

The normal way to write a loop over a range of integers in C++ is:

```
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
```

---

You are at least consistent, and have made the same mistake in every loop.  You will need to fix it in every loop.

Comment: ok! I have change my loops first loop is something like this  for( int j = 0;j ==n-1;  j++ )  and second one is for( int i  =j+1; i<n ;  i++) and the last one for( int a = 0; a<n; a++ ) but am not getting the output that i want... after executing this code last element of array should be at first but it is printing in same position.

Comment: output should be after all loops 1,3,2,6,4,8,9 but the output is 7,8,4,6,9,2,3,1

Answer (score 0):

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int  a[100][100],n,k,i,j,aux,mi=0;
 cin>>n>>k;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       for(j=1;j<=k;j++)
             cin>>a[i][j];

for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++)
     for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
          if(a[i][k]>a[j][k])
              {aux=a[i][k];
               a[i][k]=a[j][k];
               a[j][k]=aux;
             } //until here you are sorting the 2D array

             for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
                for(j=1;j<=k;j++) {
                cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
             }
cout<<endl;
  mi=a[1][1];
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
            if (mi<a[i][j])
            mi=a[i][j];
    } //here you're finding the smallest element
    cout<<mi;
    return 0;
  }
```

The Code doesn't compile, but the idea should solve 90%, you just have to write the code.